# Dependency Properties - How to add an owner so it acts as an attached property?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

Basically, is there any way to add an owner to a DependenyProperty so that it becomes an attached property of that new owner? That way I can do something like:

PrimaryControl - Original Owner
OtherControl - 2nd owner

```
<my:Something my:OtherControl.MyProperty="hello world" />
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing this? It seems like a really messy way of creating dependencies between your controls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using [AddOwner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597484.aspx). Your other control would look like:

```
public static class OtherControl {

    // MyProperty attached property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        PrimaryControl.MyPropertyProperty.AddOwner(typeof(OtherControl));

    public static string GetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj, string value) {
        obj.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
    }

}
```